# Salesforce Knowledge API - Bulk Insert/Export

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, knowledge

I reviewed the Knowledge rest api which only provides means to process single article at a time, is there a bulk api for knowledge? does anybody used SOAP API or bulk API for knowledge data integration?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by processing articles? Do you want to export all articles or modify contents?

Comment: I want to push articles to salesforce using API instead of data loader, assuming data loader is a bulk api client, did anybody try to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try use dataloader.io. It's from Mule Soft and free version is available with some limitations. Dataloder.io supports from bulkyfying.

Comment: will not work, the article data comes from different external service.

Comment: What's the nature of external service ?